# multicast socket doesn't work when using JDK 7 on Mac

Tags: macos, java, multicastsocket

I have a code about multicast sending and receiving. It can work on Mac using JDK 6. However, when I change to use JDK 7, it can't work correctly.

The code is like this:

```
final InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("228.2.3.4");
final MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(2012);

socket.setReuseAddress(true);
socket.joinGroup(group);

final int length = 8 * 1024;
final byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
final DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(bytes, length);

while(true) 
{                       
socket.receive(packet);
    ...
}
...
```

Using JDK 7 to compile and run it, it can't work when VMware running. But if using JDK 6, it can work even though VMware is running.

Besides, I try to use WireShark to monitor the adapter. And I found WireShark can see all multicast packets sent and received when using JDK 7 to run my program. But the multicast socket can't receive any.

Anyone has any idea about it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I haven't had occasion to use MultcastSockets before. Can you post some code to send packets to this address? Are they just UDP Datagrams that are sent? Post a sendPacket class and I'll check the code on windows; it looks like you discovered a bug in the JRE7 for Mac.

Comment: Calling setReuseAddress() after the socket is already bound doesn't accomplish anything. You need to reset the length of the packet every time around the loop, otherwise it keeps shrinking to the smallest length received so far.

Comment: @Thom If you haven't used multicast before, it's hard to see why you are offering to help, and why you are asking to be educated about it in a comment to somebody else's question.